# Failed to resolve play service v 7.0.0 onwards

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to sync Gradle with the following dependencies

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0' }
```

but its giving following error

[image]

after clicking on the link provided in the screenshot it opens and say the following

[image]

I'm not able to solve this problem.
My Android Repo and all support library is updated.
TIA

Comment: show your build version

Comment: Still an issue with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'`? Also, did you update both Support repository and Support library on the SDK manager?

Comment: @Koh Yea both are updated.